# Apk size vs Download size

Tags: android, size, apk, filesize

What is the difference between apk size and download size, when I analyze apk in android studio, it always shows me apks size greater than download size, what is the difference.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [APK Analyzer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer#view_file_and_size_information)...

> **Raw File Size** represents the unzipped size of the entity on disk while **Download Size** represents the estimated compressed size of the entity as it would be delivered by Google Play. The **% of Total Download Size** indicates the percentage of the APK's total download size the entity represents.