# Does the max .apk size refer to the compressed download size or the unzipped size on disk?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Ok at first glance I assume the answer to this question should be obvious. Not only because of questions that already exist (like [Apk size vs Download size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135655/apk-size-vs-download-size)) but also because the guidelines seem to state it specifically means compressed download size ("Google Play requires that the compressed APK that users download be no more than 100MB." - https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files)

However, the reason I'm seeking clarity is that fact that when I tried uploading my .apk to Google it was rejected for being too big. The raw .apk size is certainly bigger than 100 MB, but the Download Size as reported by APK Analyzer is far less than 100 MB.

Further, when I did a live chat with a Google representative about it, she seemed slightly confused about the difference between .apk file size and download size, but nevertheless just said that if the .apk was rejected for being too big then that's the end of it.

So if anyone has any insight into the issue, what I'm seeking additional information on would be:

1. Have I misunderstood the size requirements of the .apk file?
2. By what method am I able to discern what the compressed .apk size would be, if I cannot rely on APK Analyzer for it?

Comment: It is compressed apk size that shouldn't be greater than 100mb as per Google guidelines. You could use bundle whose limit is 150mb and is a common approach nowadays we follow to handle size apk restrictions.

Comment: Hi Ashok, thanks for the comment. So if I understand correctly, the download size in the APK Analyzer should reflect the compressed size? If so, can you think of why Google would've rejected my .apk, which fulfilled that criteria?

Comment: What is the actual size of release apk that you tried uploading on Playstore?

Comment: According to APK Analyzer: APK size 306 MB, Download Size 56 MB

Comment: How much size it shows if you check its size by right click on apk and see in properties? If that is exceeding 100mb which is limited by Google than you should consider using app bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Studio may compress each file individually while Play compresses the whole APK. This can result in some differences in size. Try running gzip on your APK ans check the size.

Comment: Hi Pierre, I tried that and it seemed to give the same results as APK Analyzer. It reports that the APK size is 306 MB, Download Size 56 MB, and gzip produces a file that's 55.7 MB

Comment: Ask the developer support to look into it. 56MB is << 100 MB, so unless you're uploading something completely different to what you're measuring the size of, it should work.

Comment: Sorry you'll have to pardon my ignorance - is there a suggested method of contacting developer support which is distinct from chatting with their support folks? That led me nowhere the last time (as I mentioned in the question, the person I chatted with didn't even seem to understand the difference between raw .apk size and compressed size).

Comment: Try again via email maybe, insisting you believe there is a bug and providing evidence (the APK?) so that they can forward this to engineering teams to look into. Or try uploading an AAB if that's an option.